(Synthetically) Finding the locus of the midpoint of a chord subtending a right angle at a point in a circle

Let $O$ be a point in a circle $\Gamma$, and $AB$ be any chord such that $\angle{AOB} = 90^\circ$. Find the locus of the midpoint of $AB$

My Work:
Let $PQ$ chord of the circle passing through $O$, and $XY$ be the perpendicular to $PQ$ from $O$

Clearly, $PY$, $YQ$, $QX$, and $PX$ satisfy our condition.
What I was able to prove is the following:
Points $C, D, E, F$ shall always be concylic, regardless of chord $PQ$ chosen.
Proof:
By the midpoint theorem,
$$\angle{PED} = \angle{PYX}, \angle{YEF} = \angle{YPQ}$$
Since $\angle{POY} = 90$, $\angle{PYX} + \angle{YPQ} = 90$, thus
$\angle{DEF} = 90$. Since EDFC is a parallelogram, and a rectangle, it is cyclic.
Now, I am stuck. I was given a hint but I am unable to decipher it.
Hint:
Let $Z$ be the centre of the circle. Construct a circle with radius $ZO$. Also construct a circle with centre $D$ of radius $DX$.
Can anyone help further?
Note:
Find the locus of the midpoint
Finding the locus of the midpoint of chord that subtends a right angle at $(\alpha,\beta)$
I am aware of the mentioned posts, but I'm looking for strictly synthetic solutions, and hopefully and explanation on how to utilise the hint

Hint: if you construct two perpendicular chords $AC$ and $BD$ that pass through $P$, then the midpoints of $AB, BC, CD, DA$ belong to the locus. Moreover, these four midpoints are vertices of a rectangle so they lie on a circle. Can you find its center, show that this circle is fixed, and this circle is indeed the locus?

"Hint: if you construct two perpendicular chords AC and BD that pass through P, then the midpoints of AB,BC,CD,DA belong to the locus. Moreover, these four midpoints are vertices of a rectangle so they lie on a circle." I think I already proved this, as shown in the question. I will try to do the second part. What do you mean by "find its center"?

I mean to show that the center of the circle is fixed.

As in the centre of the rectangle? ( which should also be the centre of the circle, given it exists)

Of course, the rectangle's center and its circumcenter are identical.

Something else you can use is Brahmagupta's theorem on in an inscribed quadrangle whose diagonals intersect at right angles: if segments are drawn from a midpoint of a side through the intersection of the diagonals, the extension meets the opposite side at a right angle.

Here is another approach:
A lemma first:

In the figure, if $M$ is the mid-point of $AB$, then $$2m^2=a^2+b^2-\frac{c^2}{2}$$
Proof: Apply Cosine Rule on both $\Delta CAM$ and $\Delta CBM$.
Main Proof:

Let $C$ be the center of the given circle and $D$ be the mid-point of the $OC$.
Apply our lemma on $\Delta MOC$,
$$2DM^2=MO^2+MC^2-\frac{CO^2}{2}   \tag{1}$$
Note that  $$MO=MB \tag{2}$$
and $$MB^2+MC^2=BC^2 \tag{3}$$
Putting $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$, we have
$$2DM^2=CB^2-\frac{CO^2}{2}  $$
$$DM=\sqrt{\frac{CB^2-\frac{CO^2}{2}}{2}}  $$
Note that $CB$ is the radius of the given circle and that $C$, $O$ are fixed points.
Therefore $$DM=\sqrt{\frac{CB^2-\frac{CO^2}{2}}{2}}$$ is a constant.
Therefore the locus of $M$ is a circle with radius $DM=\sqrt{\frac{CB^2-\frac{CO^2}{2}}{2}}$ and centered at the mid-point $D$ of $OC$.

Was there any motivation for you using Apollonius Theorem here?

It's a bit of luck. It just occurs to me that the locus may be a circle centered at the mid-point D of $CO$. Trying to find DM leads to Apollonius Theorem. The rest becomes straight forward.

@RobinSparrow Thanks for the informatoin! Mistakes amended.

Let $ABCD$ be the inscribed quadrilateral and $O$ the point interior to the circle, and the diagonals $AC,BD$ intersect at $O$ at right angles. This is what we are given.
At $A,B,C,D$ draw parallels to the diagonals, forming a large rectangle $FGHI$ which contains 4 rectangles in which each of $AB,BC,CD,DA$ are diagonals. This large rectangle is inscribable. Because the diagonals of rectangles bisect each other at their intersection, the midpoints of quadrilateral $ABCD$ are found halfway along the diagonals $OF, OG, OH, OI$ and therefore a dilation of $O(\frac{1}{2})$ creates from (red) circle $FGHI$ a (dashed blue) circle of half-size meeting $ABCD$ at its midpoints.
So the locus in question is a circle.

EDIT:
Calvin Lin pointed out that I hadn’t shown that the red dashed circle is the same for all orientations of the perpendicular chords. I’ll do that and a little more in this edit.
Let's call the original circle center $O_x$ and its radius $R$. The radius of the red dashed circle is a monotonic function of the distance of $O$ from $O_x$, ranging from a maximal $\sqrt{2}R$ when $O$ coincides with $O_x$ (construct the square) down to $R$ as $O$ approaches the perimeter of the circle. Another way to see that: the perpendicular chords $AC,BD$, by the Pythagorean theorem, yield the length of the diagonal of red rectangle $FGHI$ which is also the diameter of the dashed circle $FGHI$. Our maximal chords are perpendicular diameters meeting at $O_x$, and if we slide one chord along the other from the center to the side, we shrink one chord to zero and the diameter of the red circle approaches that of the black circle.

The center of the red circle coincides with the center of the black circle. This is obvious when $O$ is at $O_x$, less obvious when not. One proof that the center remains at $O_x$ is that the generation of the large red rectangle $FGHI$ could also have been described as a dilation $O(2)$ of the Varignon parallelogram $M_1M_2M_3M_4$ (generated from midpoints of $ABCD$). Generate too the extensions of $M_1O,M_2O,M_3O,M_4O$ to meet the quadrilateral sides at $F_1-F_4$. Because this is a cyclic orthodiagonal quadrilateral, we know from Brahmagupta's theorem that these extensions meet the sides at right angles. Now consider the location of the Varignon rectangle's center, $O_v$. The diagonals of bisect one another so that $O_v$, being at the midpoint of $M_1M_3$, in light of right triangle $M_3M_1F_1$, must also lie at half the distance $M_1F_1$, i.e., half the distance from $O_x$ to $O$ in that projection. This argument applies to each side, establishing that $O_v$ is the midpoint of $OO_x$. But then the dilation $O(2)$ that creates the red rectangle and red circle carries $O_v$ to $O_x$ so that the red circle has center $O_x$. The red circle remaining centered has some consequences. For example, $O$ reflects directly across each side of the quadrilateral onto the red dashed circle, reminding us of an orthocenter’s behavior relative to its feet.
Finally, the orientation of the perpendicular chords is irrelevant. We can see this algebraically pretty quickly if we call the lengths of the chords $2x=AC, 2y=BD, d=OO_x$. Using the Pythagorean theorem and the power of a point we obtain $x^2+y^2=2R^2-d^2$. But this right hand side is constant, and the left hand side is the diagonal of the large red rectangle FGHI and the diameter of the red dashed circle FGHI. So they remain constant for any configuration about a fixed $O$.

a dilation of $O(\frac{1}{2})$. Lost you there

Sure, I am not very familiar with Brahmagupta's theorem ( I only know the one about calculating area of a cyclic quadrilateral) , but I will read up on it and try to formulate a solution

Ahh, so letting $I$ be the extension of $CO$ to $YP$ then $I, E, D, F, C$ are concyclic with diameter $CE$

To check, I don't think you've shown that the locus of all possible $FGHI$, is the red circle. Can you explain why for an arbitrary $ABCD$, we land on the same red circle? It would be ideal if you described the red circle independently $\quad$ Nitpicking a bit, you have described the locus of the midpoint of AB (as a circle), but have not found the complete definition of it. Can you specify say the center and radius?

Thanks @CalvinLin, I plugged the hole
